# Easy-to-Use Regular Expression Support in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, open-source

I'm looking for a robust, easy-to-use, regular expression evaluator for native C++, either platform-independent or Windows-specific.

Requirements:

- Can't use Boost or ACE regex libraries (unfortunately)
- Can't use .NET Regex (or any managed code)

The main requirement is that it should be standalone and open.

Comment: Just curious - why can't you use boost?

Comment: @svec Because the source code is for distribution, and many of those who use it don't have Boost, and can't or don't want to download and build Boost. But some of the libraries are slated for inclusion so that's good. Should've happened 5 years ago, but hey. By all means.

Comment: But the clients don't have to have boost installed.  Just link statically with boost, and there should be no problem.  (And you should always link statically with boost anyway, since even if the clients have it installed, they may not have the same version, or have compiled it with the same options.)

Comment: @JamesKanze it's a source code dependency as we are distributing sources, not a built library. If it were up to me, every major C++ compiler and IDE would ship with Boost. In 2008 when this question was asked that was far from the case. Hard enough to get people to use STL let alone Boost.

Comment: @JamesDevlin I don't know about shipping with Boost; Boost isn't a panacea, and I choose whether to use it or not on a case by case basis.  (In fact, since I can now use C++11, I don't use Boost at all.  About all I used it for before was regular expressions.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++11 now includes the support of regular expressions.
It will be platform independent. You just need a recent compiler.
Check the following list to know which one to use.

http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Hope it helps

Comment: Link http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport goes to "Page Not Found" page.

Answer (score 12):

try [libpcre](http://www.pcre.org/)

If you're stuck on windows they have a windows port which should work. I know [e-texteditor](http://e-texteditor.com) uses it, so at least that's proof it works :-)

Answer (score 10):

If you use Visual Studio you can use Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack Release, this implements some of TR1, and includes regular expression parsing. [Get it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 10):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) has also a nice [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) implementation [QRegExp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html). It is also platform independent.

Answer (score 7):

The GNU C Library supports [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Regular-Expressions.html).  It's open, and the RE code seems to be easily extractable.

Answer (score 6):

I would second the recommendation for [PCRE](http://pcre.org). I have used it in C++ projects in Windows and it works great. It's free, even for building commercial software. It also implements something of a de facto standard regular expression language, which will be welcome to your users. PCRE is of course Perl-compatible, and Python also uses the same library.

The native PCRE interface is a bit awkward and very C-style, so it's probably worth writing a nice C++ wrapper around it. There is very likely already is one out there, but I'm not familiar with any.

Answer (score 5):

The GNU C library regular expressions facility (regcomp(), regexec() and friends) is broken. Use libetre instead; the function signatures match the ones provided by glibc.
http://laurikari.net/tre/

Answer (score 4):

C++11 and forward now contains the [standard regular expression library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).
Include the `<regex>` header, and use.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use Microsoft ATL's regex library? Kenny Kerr has written a [short article](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/07/18/visual-c-in-short-regular-expressions.aspx) on that recently.

> ATL includes a lightweight regular expression implementation. Although
>   originally part of Visual C++, it is now included with the ATL Server
>   download.
>
> The `CAtlRegExp` class template implements the parser and matching
>   engine.  ...
>
> The regular expression grammar is defined at the top of the `atlrx.h`
>   header file.

Answer (score 2):

The free ATL Server Library and Tools from CodePlex includes a regex parser. See [AtlServer in the CodePlex Archive](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=atlserver)

> ATL Server is a library of C++ classes that allow developers to build
>   both client and server parts of service-type C++ applications and web
>   services. It provides much of the functionality required to build
>   large scale internet sites, such as SOAP messaging, caching
>   facilities, threading facilities, regular expression processing,
>   management of session-state, performance monitoring, MIME support,
>   integration with IIS and class for interacting with security and
>   cryptographic infrastructure. The earlier versions of the library are
>   parts of Visual Studio 2002, Visual Studio 2003 and Visual Studio
>   2005. The project has started from the version of the library released as part of Visual Studio 2005 SP1.